# Copying elements of a 2D array into a 1D array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, copy

I'm trying to copy the elements of a 2D array into a 1D array. I know I have to use a nested loop to copy the elements, but I have no idea where to start. Here's what I have so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.IOException;

public class assignment{

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner( System.in );

        System.out.println("Welcome to Memory Game");

        int board_side;     

        do {
            System.out.println("\n For 2x2 board game press 2"+
                "\n For 4x4 board game press 4"+
                "\n For 6x6 board game press 6");
            board_side=keyboard.nextInt();
        } while(board_side!=2 && board_side!=4 && board_side!=6);

        char[][] board = createBoard(board_side);

        shuffleBoard(board);

        playGame(board); 
    }




    public static void shuffleBoard(char[][] board)
    {
        int N = board.length*board.length;
        char[] board1D = new char[N];

        // Copy the elements of 2D array into that 1D array here

    }

    public static char[][] createBoard(int side) 
    {
        char[][] tmp = new char[side][side];
        int letter_count=0;

        for (int row = 0; row < tmp.length/2; row++) {
            for(int col = 0; col < tmp[row].length; col++) {
                tmp[row][col]=(char)('A'+letter_count);
                tmp[row+tmp.length/2 ][col]=tmp[row][col];
                letter_count++;
            }
        }
        return tmp;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming its N*N matrix, you could do something like:

```
int N = board.length*board.length;
char[] board1D = new char[N];

int k = 0;
for (int i =0; i<board.length; i++) {
    for (int j =0; j<board.length; j++) {
      board1D[k++] = board[i][j];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have `m` rows and `n` columns then you need a 1-D array with `m*n` spaces.

Here is the sample code:

```
int k = 0;   // counter
int max_size = m*n; // maximum 1-D array size possible

for(i = 0; i<m; i++) {  // adjust your m and n values
    for(j = 0; j<n; j++) {
        if(k > max_size){
           // You need to consider what happens here - I simply put it as a stub
           throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Index " + k + " is out of bounds!");
        }
        target_matrix[k++] = source_matrix[i][j];
       }
 }
```

This is assuming that your indexing preference is from left to right i.e. every column first.

Please remember that my `if` statement inside the nested for loop was accounted for issues such as outofbounds exception. I wanted to make sure that you notice the chances of OutOfBounds exception. Please remove the `if block` if you don't feel you will ever need it.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you have code up there but you only need a small piece of code to understand the answer. I'm only going into how you would copy a 2 dimentional array into a 1 dimentional array. Untested code and syntax errors may abound.

```
// Presume TwoDArray contains [10][10] elements.
// Presume OneDArray contains [100] elements.

for ( column = 0; column < 10; ++column ) {
    for ( row = 0; row < 10; ++row ) {
        OneDArray[column*10 + row] = TwoDArray[column][row];
    }
}
```

The col*10 + row (I.E. columns times row size plus row) is the magic formula that converts from a 2D array to a 1D array and is actually the way a 2D array is generally stored in memory anyway, usually. (You might want to double check as it may be rows first then columns, I've seen it done differently in different languages on different platforms).

Answer (score 0):

Hi check what I did so far, I'm on the second method
http://pastebin.com/XDsp6ze7

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.IOException;

public class A{

   // main method. DO NOT MODIFY
 public static void main(String args[]) {
  Scanner keyboard = new Scanner( System.in );

  System.out.println("Welcome to Memory Game");

  int board_side;

  //this loop obtains the board size, or more specifically 
  // the length of the side of the board
  do{
   System.out.println("\n For 2x2 board game press 2"+
    "\n For 4x4 board game press 4"+
     "\n For 6x6 board game press 6");
   board_side=keyboard.nextInt();
  }while(board_side!=2 && board_side!=4 && board_side!=6);

  char[][] board = createBoard(board_side);

  // a call the the shuffle method
  shuffleBoard(board);

  // a call to the game playing method
  //playGame(board); 

 }




 // The following method should shuffle the input 2D array caled board 
 public static void shuffleBoard(char[][] board)
 {
  // This creates a 1D array whose size is equal to the size of the board   
  int N = board.length*board.length;
  char[] board1D = new char[N];

  // Copy the elements of 2D array into that 1D array here
  int a = 0;
  for (int b=0;b<board.length;b++) 
  {
    for (int c=0;c<board.length;c++) 
    {
      board1D[a] = board[b][c];
      a++;
    }
  }

  // Shuffle 1D array here 
  for (int d=0;d<board1D.length;d++)
  {
    int index=(int)(Math.random()* board1D.length);
    char temp=board1D[d];
    board1D[d]=board1D[index];
    board1D[index]=temp;
  }
   for(int row2=0;row2<board1D.length;row2++)
  {
     //System.out.print(board1D[row2] + " ");
   }

  //Copy shuffled 1D array back into 2D array, i.e., back to the board
  int M;
  if (N==4)
  {
    M=2;
  }
  else if (N==16)
  {
    M=4;
  }
  else
  {
    M=6;
  }
  int count=0;
  for (int h=0;h<M;h++)
  {
    for (int k=0;k<M;k++)
    {
      if (count==board1D.length)
      {
        break;
      }
      board[h][k]=board1D[count];
      count++;
    }
  }

   /*for(int row2=0;row2<M;row2++)
  {
    for(int col2=0;col2<M;col2++)
    {
      System.out.print(board[row2][col2]+ " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
  }*/
 }



 // a game playing method
 public static void playGame(char[][] board)
 {
  Scanner keyboard = new Scanner( System.in );

  // this createst a 2D array indicating what locations are paired, i.e., discovered
  // at the begining none are, so default initializaiton to false is ok 
  boolean[][]discovered=new boolean[board.length][board[0].length];; 


  // the code for your game playing goes here

  Still working on this part any help would be nice email: silver-saad21@hotmail.com






 }


    // createBoard method. DO NOT MODIFY!
 /* this method, createBoard, creates the board filled with letters of alphabet, 
  where each letter appears exactly 2 times
  e.g., for 4 x 4, the returned board would look like:
  A B C D 
  E F G H
  A B C D 
  E F G H */    
 public static char[][] createBoard(int side) 
 {
  char[][] tmp = new char[side][side];
  int letter_count=0;
  for (int row = 0; row < tmp.length/2; row++){
   for(int col = 0; col < tmp[row].length; col++)
   {
    tmp[row][col]=(char)('A'+letter_count);
    tmp[row+tmp.length/2 ][col]=tmp[row][col];
    letter_count++;
   }
  }
  return tmp;
 }


   // waitForPlayer method. Do not modify! 
 public static void waitForPlayer()
 {
  System.out.print("Press enter to continue");
  try {
   System.in.read();
  }
  catch (IOException e){
   System.out.println("Error reading from user");
  }
 }

}
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.